# Blank Page when run build

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build

I'm trying to deploy a project so I did an npm run build and after it to check it I did serve -s build.
but when I'm checking the building one I get a blank page but in the regular project(not build), it is working fine.
I tried to see if its a problem of routing but didn't found.

[Repo](https://github.com/ethanolle/coca-cola)

I deployed it anyway so you can see.
[Deploy of blank Page](https://cocacolascss.web.app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Package.json**

Replace from

```
"homepage": "http://ethanolle.github.io/coca-cola"
```

to

```
"homepage": "."
```

Comment: My Bad didn't saw it. Thank and sorry